# Can't able to accept linese

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install management console for chef-server

# chef-server-ctl install chef-manage 
 # chef-server-ctl reconfigure 
 # chef-manage-ctl reconfigure

These are the steps to be followed, else download deb file & unpack, but last 2 steps are for both

# chef-manage-ctl reconfigure

For this it is saying to accept license

```
devopsinfra@devopsinfra0:~$  sudo chef-manage-ctl reconfigure
To use this software, you must agree to the terms of the software license agreement.
Press any key to continue.
```

Pressing any keys shows license list, but not doing anything
Going below takes some times where las t line is "(END)", but no success

What to press after "Press any key to  continue"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing any key to continue just continues, but doesn't accept the license. Instead:

From the documentation regarding [Chef License Acceptance](https://docs.chef.io/chef_license_accept.html):

> When installed as a system package, users accept the license with the ctl command. For example, `chef-server-ctl reconfigure --chef-license=accept`. Acceptance can also be set in the configuration file chef-server.rb as `chef_license "accept"`.